# Por que o meu código retorna NAN e Infinity?

Tags: javascript, nan

(Resolvido)**Estou tentando fazer uma calculadora de IMC simples**
Porém, se eu apenas apertar o botão calcular, após o alert ele renderiza NAN como 'result'. E se eu apenas inserir o peso ele retorna um Infinity.
Fiz diversas alterações na estrutura do código mas nada resolve esse bug.

Segue o código:

```js
const heightInput = document.querySelector(".height-input");
const weightInput = document.querySelector(".weight-input");
const result = document.querySelector(".result");
const statement = document.querySelector(".statement");

document.querySelector(".calculate").addEventListener("click", calculateButton);


function calculateButton() {

  let height = heightInput.value;
  let weight = weightInput.value;
  let BMI = weight / (height ** 2);
  result.innerText = BMI.toFixed(1);

  if (BMI < 18.5) {
    statement.innerText = "Você está abaixo do peso ideal. Consulte um médico para fechar um melhor diagnóstico.";
  } else if ((BMI > 18.5) && (BMI < 24.9)) {
    statement.innerText = "Seu IMC está dentro da normalidade.";
  } else if ((BMI > 25) && (BMI < 29.9)) {
    statement.innerText = "Você está com sobrepeso. Consulte um médico para fechar um melhor diagnóstico.";
  } else if ((BMI > 30) && (BMI < 34.9)) {
    statement.innerText = "Você está com obesidade grau I. Consulte um médico para fechar um melhor diagnóstico.";
  } else if ((BMI > 35) && (BMI < 39.9)) {
    statement.innerText = "Você está com obesidade grau II. Consulte um médico para fechar um melhor diagnóstico.";
  } else if (BMI > 40) {
    statement.innerText = "Você está com obesidade grau III. Consulte um médico para fechar um melhor diagnóstico.";
  } else {
    window.alert("Por favor, adicione as informações abaixo");
  }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>IMC</title>
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Calculadora de Índice de Massa Corporal (IMC)</h1>
  </header>
  <main class="calculator-container">
    <h1>Calcule o seu IMC</h1>
    <form action="#">
      <p>Insira sua altura em metros:</p>
      <label for="height">Altura:</label>
      <input class="height-input" id="height" name="height" type="number" placeholder="Ex: 1,70" required>
      <p>Insira o seu peso em kilogramas:</p>
      <label for="weight">Peso:</label>
      <input class="weight-input" id="weight" name="weight" type="number" placeholder="Ex: 70" required>
    </form>
    <button class="calculate">Calcular</button>
    <h3 class="result"></h3>
    <p class="statement"></p>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Uma vez que os valores são obrigatórios para o cálculo, sugiro que desabilites o botão sempre que isso aconteça.

Comment: Verifique os valores **antes** de fazer o cálculo, e só o faça se os valores estiverem preenchidos corretamente. Também dá pra melhorar esses `if`'s: https://jsfiddle.net/rq5vwh3g/1/

Answer (score -3):

Acredito que você deveria checar antes se são números válidos, e então mostrar o resultado antes

```js
      function calculateButton() {
        let height = heightInput.value;
        let weight = weightInput.value;

        if (height > 0 && weight > 0) {
          let BMI = weight / height ** 2;
          if (BMI < 18.5) {
            statement.innerText =
              'Você está abaixo do peso ideal. Consulte um médico para fechar um melhor diagnóstico.';
          } else if (BMI > 18.5 && BMI < 24.9) {
            statement.innerText = 'Seu IMC está dentro da normalidade.';
          } else if (BMI > 25 && BMI < 29.9) {
            statement.innerText =
              'Você está com sobrepeso. Consulte um médico para fechar um melhor diagnóstico.';
          } else if (BMI > 30 && BMI < 34.9) {
            statement.innerText =
              'Você está com obesidade grau I. Consulte um médico para fechar um melhor diagnóstico.';
          } else if (BMI > 35 && BMI < 39.9) {
            statement.innerText =
              'Você está com obesidade grau II. Consulte um médico para fechar um melhor diagnóstico.';
          } else if (BMI > 40) {
            statement.innerText =
              'Você está com obesidade grau III. Consulte um médico para fechar um melhor diagnóstico.';
          }
        } else {
          alert('Por favor insira corretamente todos os campos');
        }
      }
```